# Access to phpmyadmin in dual booted system?

Tags: dual-boot, phpmyadmin

I have installed and configured phpmyadmin on Ubuntu. Its working fine.How can I access this from windows 7.(dual booted)

Answer (score 0):

You can't .. your webserver (apache, nginx .. or other) has to be running. And it only does so when Ubuntu is boooted.

If you want access to ubuntu from windows, you have to run either Windows or Ubuntu as virtual server in the other OS, or run Ubuntu on an other server.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you've got two operating systems installed on the same machine, Ubuntu and Win 7. On the Ubuntu installation, there's an installation of phpMyAdmin. And you try to access that phpMyAdmin instance when the machine is booted not into Ubuntu, but into Windows, correct?

That can't be done in any meaningful way. You can only run one operating system at a time. When you run Win 7, the Ubuntu installation and any applications on it are not executed, and vice versa. So there's no web server (probably Apache) to connect to, no PHP to interpret phpMyAdmins scripts. And if the MySQL server you want to manage with phpMyAdmin is running on that Ubuntu installation as well, even *that* isn't there while the machine is booted into Windows.

You might picture the situation as owning two pair of pants. You can only wear one a time, and you can only use the "features" of the pair you're wearing, not the "features" of the pair that's hanging in your closet.